# c# adding row to daatagridview deletes content of other rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am trying to add rows to a datagridview and to write someth in the new row. Bt any subsequent adding removes the content of the previews rows

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.RowCount = dataGridView2.RowCount + 1;
            dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = "smth";


                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = "something";

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
dataGridView2.Rows.Add("Smth","Something");
```

Comment: this works(I have found this on stackoverflow as well), but why my method does not

Comment: In your method, it is  changing the source of the datagridview.
In the method that  I have given it is just adding another row to the gridview.

If source is changed in datagridview it removes the previous records and takes the new record.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have problem with [ASP.NET State Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

When your `button1_Click` event is triggered, a new instance of your ASP.NET page is created and the source of your `dataGridView2` is reseted. This is why

> any subsequent adding removes the content of the previews rows

I'll try to explain with a little sample I made. With two GridViews. :
The first GridView will keep the values between clicks.

The second GridView will not keep the values between clicks and probably is the problem you're facing now.

The GridViews are equal, the Page_Load are equal, the Button Click events are equal.

The difference is between persistedList and notPersistedList

My WebForm1.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication4GridAddRow
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class SampleClass
        {
            public string PropertyA { get; set; }
            public string PropertyB { get; set; }
        }

        //I will create this in a Session List, to mantain the state.
        //You could use Viewstate (ugly!) too, this is why SamplesClass is Serializable.
        List<SampleClass> persistedList
        {
            get
            {
                return (List<SampleClass>)Session["samplesClass"];
                //return (List<SampleClass>)ViewState["samplesClass"];
            }
            set
            {
                Session.Add("samplesClass", value);
                //ViewState.Add("samplesClass", value);
            }
        }

        List<SampleClass> notPersistedList = new List<SampleClass>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                persistedList = new List<SampleClass> {
                    new SampleClass { PropertyA = "smth", PropertyB = "something" },
                    new SampleClass { PropertyA = "smthA", PropertyB = "somethingA" }
                };

                GridView1.DataSource = persistedList;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                notPersistedList = new List<SampleClass> {
                    new SampleClass { PropertyA = "smth", PropertyB = "something" },
                    new SampleClass { PropertyA = "smthA", PropertyB = "somethingA" }
                };

                GridView2.DataSource = notPersistedList;
                GridView2.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            persistedList.Add(new SampleClass { PropertyA = "smth" + persistedList.Count, PropertyB = "something" + persistedList.Count });

            GridView1.DataSource = persistedList;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notPersistedList.Add(new SampleClass { PropertyA = "smth" + notPersistedList.Count, PropertyB = "something" + notPersistedList.Count });

            GridView2.DataSource = notPersistedList;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

And WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4GridAddRow.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Using a persisted list. The values are keeped after the Button1_Click
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            Not using a persisted list. The values are lost after the Button2_Click
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I upload the sample in Git https://github.com/guiljs/c-sharp-adding-row-to-daatagridview-deletes-content-of-other-rows.git

Hope it helps you.